# OLS or Ridge in Multicollinearity data

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I am new to stats and linear regression. I just want to understand the exact scenario and usage between Ridge and OLS. Here is the data sample i have been using.

In this both Weight and BSA are highly correlated(in other words Multicollinearity). I run the following two models,

LinearRegression:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/data/bloodpress.txt', index_col=0)
input = df.drop('BP',axis=1)
output = df.BP
llr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
llr.fit(input,output)
print(llr.coef_)
print(llr.predict([[56,95.7,2.09,7.0,75,99]]))
```

O/p

```
[ 0.70325939  0.96991978  3.776491    0.06838304 -0.08448469  0.0055715 ]
[ 121.92014732]
```

Ridge:

```
input = df.drop('BP',axis=1)
output = df.BP
llr = linear_model.Ridge()
llr.fit(input,output)
print(llr.coef_)
print(llr.predict([[56,95.7,2.09,7.0,75,99]]))
```

o/p

```
[ 0.71980652  1.08207683  0.276536    0.0640874  -0.12182558  0.00696796]
[ 121.87298902]
```

When we see the o/p OLS gives better solution. The question is,

1) When i should go with Ridge? 2) In this example, Which will give better prediction ?

Comment: [Variance inflation factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) are often used to check how much coefficients are affected by multicollinearity. I think a common rule of thumb is VIF > 10 indicates bad collinearity. Not sure if these are calculated by `sklearn`'s regression models, you may have to see if other Python libraries offer it.

Comment: Often times in multiple linear regression we run into the problem of multicollinearity. Usual OLS regression tends to overestimate parameters and predictions either tend to overshoot or underperform. Either way, the better way to handle collinearity issues is to use either Ridge Regression or LASSO. LASSO is more robust than Ridge because the penalization is an absolute value function as opposed to an exponential function. Also the newest variation of these is called elastic net and uses a weighted factor to weight the penalization between ridge and LASSO.